# Go to image link in iframe after alert

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I want after click on image link in iframe and alert ok, it go to image link in iframe (That is, the image link opened in a new page.) what do i do?

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jwwppgvr/)

```js
$("body").on("click", ".mylink", function(event) {
        alert('ok'); //should alert ok
    });
```

```css
.addv {
 position:relative;
 float:left;
}
.mylink {
 position:absolute;
 top:0;
 left:0;
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
 z-index:2;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="addv"> <a class="mylink"></a> 
  <script type="text/javascript">var anetwork_pram = anetwork_pram || [];anetwork_pram["aduser"] = "1423687058";anetwork_pram["adheight"] = "250";anetwork_pram["adwidth"] = "300";</script><script type="text/javascript" src="http://static-cdn.anetwork.ir/showad/pub.js"></script> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to prevent the event to redirect you, you just need to add `event.preventDefault()` in your javascript, like this :

```
$("body").on("click", ".mylink", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    alert('ok'); //should alert ok
});
```

The click should then only trigger the alert

I would even add, since you're using jQuery, that you could replace the whole by :

```
$(".mylink").click(function(event) {
   event.preventDefault();
   alert('ok');
});
```

EDIT : I don't understand which link you want to open, but in order to add a redirection once your alert is done, just do it manually :

```
   $(".mylink").click(function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      alert('ok');
      var url = "http://www.google.com/"; //Define your url here
      window.location = url;
   });
```

EDIT EDIT : if your code is

`$(function(){
    $(".addv iframe").load(function(){
         var iBody = $(".addv iframe").contents().find("body");
         var iDiv = iBody.find("a");
        alert(iDiv.html())
         /*code to change the div content*/
    });

});`

And you get both iBody and iDiv correctly, then iDiv is a lits of all  available in your iframe, so you need to add :

```
    var a = iDiv[0]
    $(a).click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        alert("ok");
        window.location = a.href;
    }
```

Comment: ok,after alert i want go to image link (that it is in iframe).how is it?

Comment: I tried as, see it: http://jsfiddle.net/jwwppgvr/1/ for geting image link and redirection to it. but don't work for me. ?

Comment: I still don't understand what you want to do, there is no iframe in your .addv div...

Comment: Normally, when you click on the image opens a new page.Now I want to give a alert before opening a new tab.(I want to open in a new page will show the alert .) How can it be done?